# Linux Directory Access Problem: Permission Denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I'm attempting to run the command

```
username> ls -al var/
```

But I get the exception

```
ls: cannot open directory var/: Permission denied
```

When I check the permission of the directory I see

```
drwxr-x--x  6 sysuser abbagroup   4096 2010-07-28 11:55 var
```

I've confirmed that my user account is part of the group

```
> groups username
username: abbagroup
```

So why can't I run the command?

Comment: Does it show properly when you ssh or telnet to the box, as opposed to just opening a console from your desktop?

Comment: Running sudo ls -al var/
returns drwxr-x--x  6 sysuser abbagroup 4096 2010-07-28 11:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 sysuser abbagroup 4096 2010-09-08 12:45 ..
drwx--x--x  3 sysuser abbagroup 4096 2010-07-28 11:55 lib
drwx--x--x  3 sysuser abbagroup 4096 2010-07-28 11:55 log
drwx--x--x  4 sysuser abbagroup 4096 2010-07-28 11:55 run
drwx--x--x  5 sysuser abbagroup 4096 2010-07-28 11:55 spool

Comment: Does `id` also show `abbagroup` for that user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you by any chance just add `username` to `abbagroup`? This kind of change takes effect when you log in, and applies to the login process and its descendants.

When you run `groups username`, it tells you which groups `username` would belong to if (s)he logged in. Run `groups` with no argument instead, so that it tells you which groups the current process belongs to. If that doesn't show `abbagroup`, you need to log out and back in.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo ls -al var/
```

Comment: Looks like the group does to me.

Comment: You're right about the group :)